# concatenation of layers in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have a question. I have created a CNN where the output layer * has 64 output channels. I also have created a Dense layer of 16 outputs (inside the same CNN). I know that I can give multiple outputs to a CNN but I would like to have them all in the same output for the evaluation of my loss function. Therefore, my idea was to add 16 channels to output layer * where every channel contains at every pixel position the associated output of the Dense layer. My implementation:

```
denseoutput = denseoutput[:, np.newaxis, np.newaxis]
sliced = Lambda(lambda t: t[:, :, :, 0:16])(intermediate_layer)
sliced_zerod = Lambda(lambda t: t * 0)(sliced)
extra_out = Add()([sliced_zerod, decision])
x = Concatenate(axis=-1)([x, extra_out])
```

where x is my initial output layer *. The first line is to extend dimensions of the dense layer. The second and third are to get right dimensions (as I work with a dataset of different resolution images), the fourth line is an addition to get the additional output I want and the fifth line is the concatenation.

The error I get is:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_inbound_nodes'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Many things are confusing in that code. It's incomplete, contains things that are not declared, does a lot of operations to sum zero to something.... It's not currently possible to know what the problem is.

Comment: The major problem is in fact that I need the two outputs 'in the same output' because if I do outputs=[x, denseoutput], then I need a loss function for the first output and a loss function for the second one. But the output of the Dense layer has an influence on the loss function for the 'normal' CNN layer, so I need them together.

Comment: Where is that `NoneType` comes from? The problems should be around this variable.

Comment: Yes I know, I am trying to change my algorithm because this will indeed not work.

Comment: Maybe Pytorch works? It might be because you need to create the graph first in TF that using an array to create a model doesn't work.